# auto protecting the row on editing so that no one else can edit the cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I use google sheets for my business and multiple people use it and to avoid anyone editing others info I want to lock the row once the status column G says "done" and it should capture the time stamp in col H and name/email in col I.

I have tried a lot of codes but couldn't get it to work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19saOK-jdSK7IgwOQcB2sAwKvrLx7hJaF1AcOl-uyIaI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets Script to lock or unlock a row depending on the value in the cell of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074339/google-sheets-script-to-lock-or-unlock-a-row-depending-on-the-value-in-the-cell)

Comment: As additional information to @Tedinoz 's comment, if about `and name/email in col I`, you want to retrieve the information of edit user, unfortunately, in the current stage, this cannot be achieved by the current specification. I'm worried about it.

Comment: I was interested in @Tanaike 's comment: `this cannot be achieved by the current specification`.  Answer: `getActiveUser()` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) "Gets information about the current user. [...] The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger..."

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. I think in the above link when the value is x the row can't be edited when the value is O the row can be edited. But in my case I don't want to values to be edited. once the data in row is entered the cell will be marked as "done" and then the row gets locked including the cell in which we enter "done". I hope I was able to communicate exactly what I meant, apologies if I'm irritating with my english.

Comment: @Tedinoz. I tried that link which u sent me but I donot know the reason it is not working. could you please go through the code in the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19saOK-jdSK7IgwOQcB2sAwKvrLx7hJaF1AcOl-uyIaI/edit?usp=sharing